# Throughput effect in JMeter's Throughput Controller

Tags: jmeter, throughput

I received a JMeter script from someone, a script that contains **3 Throughput Controllers**. The strange part is that they have **"Percent Executions"** selected and summing the **Throughput** from each of the controllers I only reach **70** ( the First one has a throughput of 40, second one 20 and third one 10). **The questions are:**

**1.** Shouldn't their sum be 100 (100%) ?

**2.** If the sum is 70 and the first one has a throughput of 40, does it mean that the first throughput controller will run 40% of the sum of 70?

**3.** Could someone give me more details related to "Percent executions vs Total executions"?

-JMeter help doesn't help much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Throughput Controller** can operate in **2 modes**:

1. **Total Executions** **:-** defines how many times the child elements will be executed (absolute number).

   **(A)**. If “**Per User**” is unchecked **-** the underlying sampler(s) will be executed as many times as defined in the Throughput field. For instance, if you have 100 users, the throughput of 100 and the box is unchecked, the underlying test elements will be executed 100 times.

   **(B)**. If “**Per User**” is checked - the child sampler(s) will be executed as many times as defined in the Throughput field, multiplied by the “Number of Threads” in the current Thread Group. For instance, if you have 100 users, the throughput of 100 and the box is checked, underlying test elements will be executed 100,000 times.
2. **Percent Executions**:- the child elements will be executed according to the percentage of iterations (threads * loops) as defined in the Throughput” field.

All these information is quoted from BlazeMeter Blog about [Using Throughput Controller with Different Execution Percentages](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability). This blog will help you understand your test executions scenario as per your configuration of [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) inside the Test Script.